# What number should be replaced by? How and Why

Tags: number-sequence

What number should replace the ?

(1,3),(6,8),(6,9),(7,3),(2,4),(6,4),(?,6),(7,2)

[image: Number in ?]

Answer (score 6):

> 4. $6\times3=18, 7\times9=63, 6\times4=24, 7\times6=42$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful